# Вывести значения Checkbox на страницу

Tags: javascript, checkbox

> Есть выпадающий список с выбором "модели кровати", "ширины" и чекбокс выбор услуги "Нанесение краски"

```
<select name="model_krovat" id="model" class="form-control">
    <option  selected="selected" value="6300">Белава</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" name="shirina_krovat" id="shirina">
    <option   value="0">800</option>
    <option   value="500">900</option>
    <option   value="1000">1000</option>
    <option   value="1000">1100</option>
</select>
<label for="yslygi">Нанесение краски
<input type="checkbox"  onchange="calculate()"  id="yslygi" /
```

> Код сумма значений выпадающего списка и чекбокса

```
function calculate() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('select').each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    if ($("#yslygi").is(':checked'))
    {
        if  (($('#shirina').val() == "0")) sum += 2500;
        switch ($('#shirina option:selected').text())
        {case "900" : sum+=100; break;
            case "1000": sum+=100; break;
            case "1100": sum+=200; break;
        }
    }
    $('#final_price').html(sum);
}
$('select,input').change(function() {
    calculate();
});
```

> Нужно, чтобы по умолчаю рядом с чекбоксом стояла цена 2500 руб.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> После нажатия на чекбокс изменялось значение, из формулы
>    `case "900" : sum+=100; break;`
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: дополните просто кейсы заполнением требуемого блока, в чем проблема-то конкретно?

Comment: не знаю как именно это сделать

Comment: что конкретно не знаете? Как приделать новый блок под цену? Как заполнить блок текстовым значением? Попробуйте сами решить эту подзадачку и дополните свой вопрос попытками, вам надо научиться решать базовые задачи, а то так и будете по каждой мелочи бежать на форум :)

Comment: хорошо,извините...

Comment: Главное не опускайте руки, пробуйте сами решать задачи и показывайте свои попытки, так и проще учиться и отвечать на такие вопросы гораздо приятнее, поэтому вероятность получить помощь будет выше. Один плюсы!

Comment: Пытаюсь)все равно надо сделать

Comment: можете подсказать я хоть в правильном направлении: for (var i=0; i<yslygiElem.value; ++){
  document.getElementById('yslygi') = rezultatchekbox.value;

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73765/discussion-between-yolosora-and-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     Стоимость: <span id="final_price">6300</span> Руб.
<p>Модель</p>
<p>Ширина</p>
<select name="model_krovat" id="model">
           <option  selected="selected" value="6300">Белава</option>
        </select></p>
<select name="shirina_krovat" id="shirina">

      <option   value="500">900</option>
      <option   value="1000">1000</option>
     </select>
<label for="yslygi">Нанесение краски 
<input type="checkbox"  onchange="calc()"  id="yslygi" /> 
<span id="price1">2500</span>
```

> Для того, что бы отображалось значение у checkbox мне подсказали добавить новую переменную prinprice

```
  function calculate() {
  var sum = 0;

  $('select').each(function() {

    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  //задаем начальное значение переменной для checkbox
  var prinprice1 = 0;

  //покраска по размерам взяли значения из текста селекта
  if ($("#yslygi").is(':checked'))

  {
    switch ($('#shirina option:selected').text()) {
      case "900":
        sum += 100;
        prinprice1 += 100;
        break;
      case "1000":
        sum += 100;
        prinprice1 += 200;
        break;
    }


    //вывод значения чекбокса
    $('#price1').html(prinprice1);
  }

  //итоговая цена
  $('#final_price').html(sum);

}

$('select,input').change(function() {
  calculate();
});
```

Comment: Мне нужно автоматически менять значения у checkbox при нажатии на select. Переставляла $('#price1').html(prinprice1); ниже по коду, показывает при запуске 0. Что я делаю не так? Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Ну так у вас только по ширине идет расчет и только двум значениям

Comment: Это я так сократила

Comment: В таком случае из предоставленной информации нельзя сказать почему такое происходит

Comment: а вывод значения чекбокса правильно я вывела?может его перенести?

Comment: Если значение суммы покраски должно появляться только при чекнутом чекбоксе, то да